# search for timestamp range in 2 dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$data= "Array ( 
    [0] => 1520155838|1234|2000|Name1|COMPLETE|2|18|1
    [1] => 1520156051|1234|2000|Name2|COMPLETE|20|3|1 
    [2] => 1520165693|1234|2000|Name3|COMPLETE|3|15|1 
    [3] => 1520166218|1234|2000|Name4|COMPLETE|26|71|1 
    [4] => 1522128854|1234|2000|Name5|COMPLETE|77|121|1 
    [5] => 1522129106|1234|2000|Name6|COMPLETE|221|244|1 
)";
```

and I need to search and return keys that within time-stamp range "1520155840" and "1520165699" for example.

I exploded it with:

```
$Data_Array=[];
for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($data); $x++) {    
    array_push($Data_Array, explode("|",$data[$x]));
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: It's not multidimensional array. 2-dimensional means `Array of Arrays`, 3-dimensional is `Array of Arrays of Arrays`. And this is just 1-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the given is an array and not a string.

You can use `array_filter` to filter the array between the given range. This will preserve the key of the original array

```
$data= array( 
    "1520155838|1234|2000|Name1|COMPLETE|2|18|1",
    "1520156051|1234|2000|Name2|COMPLETE|20|3|1",
    "1520165693|1234|2000|Name3|COMPLETE|3|15|1",
    "1520166218|1234|2000|Name4|COMPLETE|26|71|1",
    "1522128854|1234|2000|Name5|COMPLETE|77|121|1",
    "1522129106|1234|2000|Name6|COMPLETE|221|244|1",
);

$fr = "1520155840";
$to = "1520165699";


$result = array_filter($data, function($v) use($fr, $to){
    $v = explode("|",$v);
    return $fr <= $v[0] && $to >= $v[0];
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1520156051|1234|2000|Name2|COMPLETE|20|3|1
    [2] => 1520165693|1234|2000|Name3|COMPLETE|3|15|1
)
```

Doc: [filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)